# How to add this function 'setInterval' on this code to make my page fetch forms or data without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have ajax and javascript, now i am fetching this modal to another page or to another separate browser.

For now I can fetch the modal but I needed it to refresh the page before the modal will show. how can I do it without clicking refresh. I've done some research and I've seen `setInterval` function but how should i implement it through my code thanks! all I want is  to not refresh the page before the modal will show.

**Onto my modal form here it is, this is the code whereas after I submit the submit button**

```js
if ($count != 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
          echo '<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="position:fixed;  display: none; padding-top: 100px; 
          left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); ">
                <div class="container" style="width: 100%">
                <div class="card col-12" style="background-color: red; color: white;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p><h3 class="text-center">Announcement</h3></p>
                </div>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                      <h5>'.$row['additional_info'].'</h5>
                      <p>Please click refresh button to resume after the announcement</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                </div>';
              $dataid = $row['id'];
      }
  }
```

here it is the script where I want to put the **setInterval** function for the page to automatically not refresh

```js
document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='block';
```

for now it has no any special code that is just how I show the modal but it needed to be refresh

I expect the output of the modal should be display once i already click the submit button. and for my code the button was already click and i just want to insert the `setInterval` function for the modal to show without refreshing the page

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Comment: @obfish there it is edited thanks to exaneta, sorry

Comment: So you have a submit button and you need to show the modal when that button is clicked, is that it?

Comment: yes sir! that's it

Answer (score 0):

refresh

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="addon/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="modalid">
        </div>

        <button onclick="ra()">REFRESH</button>

        <script>
            function ra() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "testajax.php",
                    data: { val : "ann" },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data.status == "OK") {
                            document.getElementById("modalid").innerHTML = data.value
                            setTimeout( function() { document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = 'none'; }, 3000);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert(data.value)
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ajax

```
<?php

$jStatus = "ERROR";
$jValue = "";

$val = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "val");
if($val == 'ann') {
    $jStatus = "OK";
    $jValue = "<div id='myModal' class='modal' style='position:fixed; display: block; padding-top: 100px; 
          left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); '>
                <div class='container' style='width: 100%'>
                <div class='card col-12' style='background-color: red; color: white;'>
                <div class='card-header'>
                    <p><h3 class='text-center'>Announcement</h3></p>
                </div>
                  <div class='card-body text-center'>
                      <h5>HELLLOOO</h5>
                      <p>Please click refresh button to resume after the announcement</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img class='modal-content' id='img01'>
                </div>";
}

$jsonReply = array( "status" => $jStatus, "value" => $jValue);

echo json_encode($jsonReply);

?>
```

is this what you want?

Comment: so the `testajax.php` is the one below after the html?

Comment: nothing is showing :( but yeah so far that is what i want

Comment: button on refresh will be request ajax to testajax.php.
testajax.php will reply with modal
then refresh will parse the result and dismiss the modal after 3 secs

Comment: its two different file. refresh could be index.php then ajax should be testajax.php, please change the jquery address with your address